# Moving Linux Mint 18.3 from its own drive to one shared with Windows 7

Tags: linux-mint

I've been test-driving Linux Mint 18.3 on my main desktop(The last computer to convert) for about 3 weeks now and I'm ready to make the switch permanently. The problem is, I installed it onto a laptop drive by itself, and Windows 7's OS is on a 512GB SSD. I've resized Windows already to make space, but I'm not sure what the best way is to copy Linux over. I'd like to end up with a dual-bootable system.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to Linux, I would recommend simply re-installing on the other drive.  The installer will prompt to replace Windows entirely, set up a dual boot, or "something else".  Pick the dual boot option.

After the install, simply copy over the contents of your `~/` (home directory) and reinstall any extra applications/packages you've installed on your test system.

Comment: I'm not new to Linux, I've been using it for years. I just haven't used it on my desktop(laptops and servers only). A migration would be highly preferable.